# add new field in magento(1.9) in admin customer creation only

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello a i need i add new filed admin customer creation form, the field name is VIP, i search so many links related to my requirement but not in magento(1.9).

can you please give some idea related to my requirement.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below script to create customer attribute

```
<?php
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'vip', array(
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'VIP',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
));

$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'vip',
    '100'
);

$oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'vip');

$oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer','customer_account_edit')); 
$oAttribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

You can change input type as per your requirement.

Comment: In that file I need to enter this code

Comment: You can create a module and add this code in setup script or just create one sample attribute.php file on root  paste above code but before that code add require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app(); in file and run in browser directly. It will create new attribute in system.

Comment: and if you need to remove a field change much code
Thanks for everything

Answer (score 2):

You can use below script to create customer attribute visible in admin customer creation form

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup(); 
$installer->addAttribute("customer", "vip",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "VIP",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "" 
));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "vip");         
$used_in_forms=array(); 
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
          ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
          ->setData("is_system", 0)
          ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
          ->setData("is_visible", 0)
          ->setData("sort_order", 100);
$attribute->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

You can change input type as per your requirement.